# javascript push method on global object array overwrites all values in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, push

I've reviewed previous posts on this problem, but have not been able to get the generally proposed solution to work for me. evtList is a global array of objects of type "Event". Previous posts have indicated that creating a local object ("newEvent") inside my loop, defining it's elements, and then pushing the local object into the global array should work. However, I've found that as soon as I declare a new value for an element in the newEvent object, all the objects in the global array are changed to that set of values even before the push operation. What have I missed?

```
var i = 0;
var nextTime = new Date();

while (evtList[i].evtTime < dayEnd) {
    i++;
    var newEvent = new Event;
    var milliSecs = (evtList[i-1].evtTime).getTime() + gaussian(arrStations[0].mean, arrStations[0].stdDev);
    nextTime.setTime(milliSecs);
    newEvent = ({value: 1, station: 0, evtTime: nextTime});

    evtList.push(newEvent);
}
```

Comment: you're adding to the array you're looping over?

Comment: Why do you assume that the object are the same? They are differnt object, but the `evtTime` will be the same for all objects because they all reference the same date (`nextTime`). Beside that, the `newEvent` element you push is a plain JavaScript object and not an object of the type `Event`.

Comment: the next time value would change even before you push since you are updating  the same reference which is present of all newEvent objects......so even though you are adding a new object....the constituents of the object have the same values......this is why you see that all objects have the same value

Comment: I'm building an array of timeline events (objects). Each new event occurs at a normally distributed interval after the previous event. The timeline stops when it reaches or surpasses the dayEnd Date value set by the user.,

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript `var` does not define a block level scope but a function level scope, so `newEvent` is not local to the your for loop, but to the the function body it belongs to, or to the global scope if it is not in a function.

With you `push` you add different objects to your  `evtList`, but the problem is that the property `evtTime` of each of your objects reference the same `Date` object, so with `nextTime.setTime(milliSecs)` you will change the date for all of your `evtTime`  properties, because it is the same object.

You would need to create a new `Date` object for each of you objects:

```
var newEvent;
var milliSecs;
var nextTime;
var i = 0;

while (evtList[i].evtTime < dayEnd) {
  i++;
  // newEvent = new Event;
  nextTime = new Date;
  milliSecs = (evtList[i - 1].evtTime).getTime() + gaussian(arrStations[0].mean, arrStations[0].stdDev);
  nextTime.setTime(milliSecs);
  newEvent = ({
    value: 1,
    station: 0,
    evtTime: nextTime
  });

  evtList.push(newEvent);
}
```

The `newEvent` you push to your `evtList` is not of the type `Event`, because the `Event` object that you have created with `newEvent = new Event` overwritten by a plain JavaScript object here:

```
newEvent = ({
  value: 1,
  station: 0,
  evtTime: nextTime
});
```

You either want to set just the properties of the newly created `Event` object:

```
newEvent.value = 1;
newEvent.station = 0;
newEvent.evtTime = nextTime;
```

Or you might pass them to your `Event` constructor.

Comment: Perfect! That worked! Thank you so much for your help.